# Mate PropertyInjectors - Inject to as3 class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mate

Does anyone know if it is possible to inject into a regular as3 (non mxml) class? I've tried with limited success.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you be more specific? There's no difference between an "MXML" class and a class defined in ActionScript, it's just different ways of writing the same thing.

All that is needed for injection to work is a source property that is bindable and a destination property that is public (either a public setter or a public instance variable). If those two requirements are met and the code compiles it should work.

Look at the code for the example application you can find here: http://code.google.com/p/mate-examples/wiki/DocumentBasedExampleIntro and you will find a ton of injectors that target classes not defined using MXML (look for injectors targeting classes whose names end in "Model" especially). You can also find countless examples in the [Mate forums](http://mate.asfusion.com/forums).

Comment: Thanks Theo, I met all the above requirements but on instantiation of the object the setter was not being called. I will persevere with the knowledge that it can be done. However I thought that maybe the fact that mate is a flex specific framework could have been the reason I was having no joy. Cheers